# How to retrive json result values in javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript function which redirects to given url after i had a json result.I want this json result values in my html inputs on success.Please help me i am new to MVC

```
 function GetSupplierDetail(SupId) {
        var url = "/PurchaseOrders/GetSupplierDetails/";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { SuppId: SupId },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.modelList);
            },
            error: function (reponse) {

            }
        });

    }
```

This is my C# Action.

```
 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult GetSupplierDetails(int SuppId)
            {  var books = entity.P_Supplier.Where(x => x.SupplierId == SuppId).ToList();

          var modelList = books.Select(x => new SupplierModel()
     {

                                         Firm = x.Firm,
                               Sname = x.Sname,
                              SupplierName=x.SupplierName,
                               Address1=x.Address1,
                               Cell=x.Cell,
                               Email=x.Email,
                             Fax=x.Fax

                               });
           return Json(modelList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what the problem is? What exactly is not working?

Comment: I want to Supplier's Details on DropDown change id goes to given action where i retrive the data from database after that i return using json and then wants to fill all my textboxes in success function .but i got null in where i put alert(data.modelList).

Comment: OK, can you update your question with the fact that data.modelList is `null`? Also, have you watched what's being received in the browser using F12 tools, to verify that the JSON is actually being sent back correctly?

Comment: My issue is on both c# side also in javscript side. What is the correct syntax for sending value using c# in controller and how it is get in javscript in html inputs.Right now json is null.

Comment: You should set a breakpoint at the start of the `GetSupplierDetails` method and verify that `SuppId` is non-zero and that `books.Select` actually returns some data.

Comment: books result in count=1 but modelList no result i want right syntax how i return all fields in json and get in javascript respectively.

Comment: So what is the result of `console.log(data)` in the `success` function? because when you send back the serialised `modelList`, data *is* the modelList; it won't contain a property called "modelList"...

Comment: console.log(data) show values that i need.Works ,Further how i get the each object value in my textbox

Comment: so therefore don't use `data.modelList`, you just use `data` *directly as the list*. If you need help binding this list of objects to HTML elements, I'd suggest a separate question at this stage, for clarity's sake.

Answer (score -1):

alert(data.modelList); returns object which contains a collection.You need to loop over that collection.If you want to bind collection with GridView then there are different open source grids are available i.e Backgrid,flexigrid. 
If there is just single result then you can check it by alert(data.modelList.Firm);
or assign it to any input fields.
$('#txtFirm').val(data.modelList.Firm);

Comment: Put a break point near modelList in controller and check it.Is it is null or not.

Comment: data: { JSON.stringify({SuppId: SupId })},

Comment: return Json(modelList)

Comment: var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data.output);
if (parseInt(jsonObject.length) > 0)
{
alert( jsonObject[0].Firm);
}
}

Comment: var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data.output); if (parseInt(jsonObject.length) > 0) { alert( jsonObject[0].Firm); } } not worked As jsonObject is null.